# In short, what does this mean? rvm ruby oh my zsh

Tags: rvm, osx-elcapitan, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

What does this mean?

```
--- ~ » $PATH

zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/Reed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/bin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/bin
```

What is wrong? I think zsh is working?

Comment: Can you give more context? If you don't expand upon your question we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

zsh is operating just fine. `$PATH` is a variable and when you type `$PATH` it is the same as typing what `$PATH` is equal to. In your case `$PATH` equals:

```
/Users/Reed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/bin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Reed/.rvm/bin
```

The `$PATH` variable is great! It contains multiple directories separated by colons. This is used by your shell to let you run commands nicely without having to use the full path all the time.

So, when you typed `--- ~ » $PATH` you are really just typing ALL of these directories with colons in between.

And - as you may have guessed - this is not a command that your shell recognizes, so your shell responds with: `zsh: no such file or directory:`

bash does the same thing!

Comment: The problem is from about a month ago. I solved it, but I can't remember how at this point. Thanks for checking in on it.